# Access to iBooks elements from iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, ibooks

I want to access to the elements listed in iBooks App (Books and/or PDFs). Exists some class or method that can help me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, if you need this and have a good reason, you should file a bug report and tell them why exactly you need this feature.